# An error related icon in Mac app submission

Tags: cocoa, xcode4, icons, app-store, mac-app-store

I am getting error while submitting Mac app.

[image]

Here is my info.plist file.

[image]

I have also added icon@2x.icns (1024x1024) icon to the app still it is giving this error.
(icon.icns is 512x512 icon)

Please tell me where i am wrong. Your suggestions would be great help.
Thank you.

Comment: Not sure, but I think you should have a single icns file that contains all resolutions.

Comment: Thanks omz..!! but how can i get all in one? I am using icon composee and its not possible in this i think. Any suggestions ??

Comment: The [Icon Design Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/applehiguidelines/IconsImages/IconsImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000967-TP6) have a chapter called "Packaging Your Icon Resources" that describes how to make a high-res icns file using the command line. It also says specifically that you cannot use Icon Composer for this.

Comment: +1 for saving ma day. Thanks..!! :)

Comment: Betcha he hasn't saved your day yet... just a premonition... ;)